# Php function order color by lightness

Tags: php, sorting, colors

Is it possible to sort colors by php on lightness .

Now i calc the differenct with this function

```
public function colorDiff($rgb1,$rgb2)
{
        // do the math on each tuple
        // could use bitwise operates more efeceintly but just do strings for now.
        $red1 = hexdec(substr($rgb1,0,2));
        $green1 = hexdec(substr($rgb1,2,2));
        $blue1 = hexdec(substr($rgb1,4,2));

        $red2 = hexdec(substr($rgb2,0,2));
        $green2 = hexdec(substr($rgb2,2,2));
        $blue2 = hexdec(substr($rgb2,4,2));

        return abs($red1 - $red2) + abs($rgreen1 - $green2) + abs($blue2 - $blue2) ;

}
```

But this will not sort images on lightness.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting by Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261033/sorting-by-color)

Comment: it would also be wise to not hard code the string lengths in your function... 255,255,255 or 25,25,25 or #FFDDCC or #FDC are different and would cause problems with the way you have your function layed out..

Comment: notice that it's not first your question where your problem is that you try to use human-ubderstandable words(lightness, closest color). This words can't help you with PC. PC need facts, numbers, etc

Answer (score 4):

You can get a decent value for luminance (the [perceived lightness](http://gimp-savvy.com/BOOK/index.html?node54.html)) with the following formula:

```
$red * .3 + $green * .59 + $blue * .11
```

Quoting from the linked article:

> The explanation for these weights is due to the fact that for equal amounts of color the eye is most sensitive to green, then red, and then blue. This means that for equal amounts of green and blue light the green will, nevertheless, seem much brighter."

Answer (score 1):

1) You need math defination of lightness. So it should function from color to integer that represent lightness

2) If you suppose (for example) than it is sum of $red+$green+$blue you can use this kind of sort

```
 usort($colors,function ($rgb1,$rgb2){
    $red1 = hexdec(substr($rgb1,0,2));
    $green1 = hexdec(substr($rgb1,2,2));
    $blue1 = hexdec(substr($rgb1,4,2));

    $red2 = hexdec(substr($rgb2,0,2));
    $green2 = hexdec(substr($rgb2,2,2));
    $blue2 = hexdec(substr($rgb2,4,2));

    return ($red1+$green1+$blue1) - ($reg2+$green2+$blue2);
 })
```

Comment: The above definition of lightness is reasonable -- it should be understood as the "taxicab" or "manhattan" distance from the color black.

Another reasonable alternative would be to use the generalized distance formula... black is a vector <0, 0, 0> and the color in question is <r, g, b>.  i.e. take the square root of the sum of the squares of component differences.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your RGB color to HSL colorspace and the sort on the `L` component:
http://axonflux.com/handy-rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-c