# Sort Hex Color Values

Tags: sorting, colors, hex

I have a color table related to products. The value of colors which is a hexadecimal is saved in a nvarchar field.
In the products section I have a dropdown List for colors of a specified product.
So I need to sort these colors from lighter to darker...
I'm using MVC 3.0 and writting C# code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting by Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261033/sorting-by-color)

Answer (score 4):

You want to get their intensity, so convert from RGB to HSV. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261033/sorting-by-color/1261052#1261052) for more details.