# Sorting Hex Color in decreasing order of darkness in Java

Tags: java, colors, hex, hsl

I am looking for a method to sort a list of hex colors from dark to light / light to dark i.e all shades of red must be sorted like Dark Red to lighter red to pink. There might be shades of other colors in the list as well. I want to first show sorted shades of red then sorted shades of other colors in any order i.e sorted red,sorted blue,sorted green etc.

I first converted RGB to HSB/HSL and then sorted it referring to the posts([Sort Hex Color Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434347/sort-hex-color-values) , [Sort list of colors by HSV/HSB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651781/sort-list-of-colors-by-hsv-hsb))

I implemented the basic test version in Java using the code below

```
  public class classA {
  public static Color hex2Rgb(String colorStr) {
    return new Color(
          Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 1, 3 ), 16 ),
          Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 3, 5 ), 16 ),
          Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 5, 7 ), 16 ) );
     }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  String hex = "#FFFFFF";
  ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
  colors.add("#FFA07A");
  colors.add("#FA8072");
  colors.add("#E9967A");
  colors.add("#F08080");
  colors.add("#CD5C5C");
  colors.add("#DC143C");
  colors.add("#B22222");
  colors.add("#FF0000");
  colors.add("#8B0000");
  colors.add("#800000");
  colors.add("#FF6347");
  colors.add("#FF4500");
  colors.add("#DB7093");

  ArrayList<Color> colorArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String s : colors) {
     Color colorcode = hex2Rgb(s);
     colorArrayList.add(colorcode);
  }
  Collections.sort(colorArrayList, new Comparator<Color>() {
     @Override
     public int compare(Color c1, Color c2) {
        float[] hsb1 = Color.RGBtoHSB(c1.getRed(), c1.getGreen(), c1.getBlue(), null);
        float[] hsb2 = Color.RGBtoHSB(c2.getRed(), c2.getGreen(), c2.getBlue(), null);
        if (hsb1[0] < hsb2[0])
           return -1;
        if (hsb1[0] > hsb2[0])
           return 1;
        if (hsb1[1] < hsb2[1])
           return -1;
        if (hsb1[1] > hsb2[1])
           return 1;
        if (hsb1[2] < hsb2[2])
           return -1;
        if (hsb1[2] > hsb2[2])
           return 1;
        return 0;
     }
  });
  ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
  for(Color c: colorArrayList){
     String hexc = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue());
     res.add(hexc);
  }
  for(String s: res){
     System.out.println(s);
  }
```

}

This does not seem to work for my use case. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: A possible way without using AWT libraries would be better.