# How to display rgb value of an image as percentage

Tags: php, image, colors, rgb

I would like to display RGB value of an images as percentage.

For example, if hex color is `#000000`, How do I display it as % code (percentage) like rgb(0%,0%,0%)?

Comment: Did you google?, if so, have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202079/convert-hex-color-to-rgb-values-in-php

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
function hex2rgb($hex) {
   $hex = str_replace("#", "", $hex);

   if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
      $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,1).substr($hex,0,1));
      $g = hexdec(substr($hex,1,1).substr($hex,1,1));
      $b = hexdec(substr($hex,2,1).substr($hex,2,1));
   } else {
      $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
      $g = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
      $b = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
   }
   $rgb = array($r, $g, $b);
   //return implode(",", $rgb); // returns the rgb values separated by commas
   return $rgb; // returns an array with the rgb values
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array ( [0] => 204 [1] => 204 [2] => 0 )
//rgb(204,204,0)
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/DEMht)**