# PHP longhand hex to RGB not working correctly

Tags: php, hex, background-color, rgb, rgba

How do I convert longhand hex to RGB(A)?
For example, I have the following code to convert all formats of hex, colorname, etc.. to RGBA for background opacity, but for some reason longhand hex does not work, but instead takes the shorthand from the longhand (eg. `background-color: #0000ff;` becomes `background-color: #000;`).
Alot of the code below is based off of [Convert hex color to RGB values in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202079/convert-hex-color-to-rgb-values-in-php) but that question and similar questions are not able to resolve my issue. I spent 2 weeks looking for an answer to this, and have yet to find one, so I come here.

#### Color name to hex function:

```
function color_name_to_hex($color_name) {
    $colors  =  array(
        'aliceblue'=>'F0F8FF',
        'antiquewhite'=>'FAEBD7',
        'aqua'=>'00FFFF',
        'aquamarine'=>'7FFFD4',
        'azure'=>'F0FFFF',
        'beige'=>'F5F5DC',
        'bisque'=>'FFE4C4',
        'black'=>'000000',
        'blanchedalmond '=>'FFEBCD',
        'blue'=>'0000FF',
        'blueviolet'=>'8A2BE2',
        'brown'=>'A52A2A',
        'burlywood'=>'DEB887',
        'cadetblue'=>'5F9EA0',
        'chartreuse'=>'7FFF00',
        'chocolate'=>'D2691E',
        'coral'=>'FF7F50',
        'cornflowerblue'=>'6495ED',
        'cornsilk'=>'FFF8DC',
        'crimson'=>'DC143C',
        'cyan'=>'00FFFF',
        'darkblue'=>'00008B',
        'darkcyan'=>'008B8B',
        'darkgoldenrod'=>'B8860B',
        'darkgray'=>'A9A9A9',
        'darkgreen'=>'006400',
        'darkgrey'=>'A9A9A9',
        'darkkhaki'=>'BDB76B',
        'darkmagenta'=>'8B008B',
        'darkolivegreen'=>'556B2F',
        'darkorange'=>'FF8C00',
        'darkorchid'=>'9932CC',
        'darkred'=>'8B0000',
        'darksalmon'=>'E9967A',
        'darkseagreen'=>'8FBC8F',
        'darkslateblue'=>'483D8B',
        'darkslategray'=>'2F4F4F',
        'darkslategrey'=>'2F4F4F',
        'darkturquoise'=>'00CED1',
        'darkviolet'=>'9400D3',
        'deeppink'=>'FF1493',
        'deepskyblue'=>'00BFFF',
        'dimgray'=>'696969',
        'dimgrey'=>'696969',
        'dodgerblue'=>'1E90FF',
        'firebrick'=>'B22222',
        'floralwhite'=>'FFFAF0',
        'forestgreen'=>'228B22',
        'fuchsia'=>'FF00FF',
        'gainsboro'=>'DCDCDC',
        'ghostwhite'=>'F8F8FF',
        'gold'=>'FFD700',
        'goldenrod'=>'DAA520',
        'gray'=>'808080',
        'green'=>'008000',
        'greenyellow'=>'ADFF2F',
        'grey'=>'808080',
        'honeydew'=>'F0FFF0',
        'hotpink'=>'FF69B4',
        'indianred'=>'CD5C5C',
        'indigo'=>'4B0082',
        'ivory'=>'FFFFF0',
        'khaki'=>'F0E68C',
        'lavender'=>'E6E6FA',
        'lavenderblush'=>'FFF0F5',
        'lawngreen'=>'7CFC00',
        'lemonchiffon'=>'FFFACD',
        'lightblue'=>'ADD8E6',
        'lightcoral'=>'F08080',
        'lightcyan'=>'E0FFFF',
        'lightgoldenrodyellow'=>'FAFAD2',
        'lightgray'=>'D3D3D3',
        'lightgreen'=>'90EE90',
        'lightgrey'=>'D3D3D3',
        'lightpink'=>'FFB6C1',
        'lightsalmon'=>'FFA07A',
        'lightseagreen'=>'20B2AA',
        'lightskyblue'=>'87CEFA',
        'lightslategray'=>'778899',
        'lightslategrey'=>'778899',
        'lightsteelblue'=>'B0C4DE',
        'lightyellow'=>'FFFFE0',
        'lime'=>'00FF00',
        'limegreen'=>'32CD32',
        'linen'=>'FAF0E6',
        'magenta'=>'FF00FF',
        'maroon'=>'800000',
        'mediumaquamarine'=>'66CDAA',
        'mediumblue'=>'0000CD',
        'mediumorchid'=>'BA55D3',
        'mediumpurple'=>'9370D0',
        'mediumseagreen'=>'3CB371',
        'mediumslateblue'=>'7B68EE',
        'mediumspringgreen'=>'00FA9A',
        'mediumturquoise'=>'48D1CC',
        'mediumvioletred'=>'C71585',
        'midnightblue'=>'191970',
        'mintcream'=>'F5FFFA',
        'mistyrose'=>'FFE4E1',
        'moccasin'=>'FFE4B5',
        'navajowhite'=>'FFDEAD',
        'navy'=>'000080',
        'oldlace'=>'FDF5E6',
        'olive'=>'808000',
        'olivedrab'=>'6B8E23',
        'orange'=>'FFA500',
        'orangered'=>'FF4500',
        'orchid'=>'DA70D6',
        'palegoldenrod'=>'EEE8AA',
        'palegreen'=>'98FB98',
        'paleturquoise'=>'AFEEEE',
        'palevioletred'=>'DB7093',
        'papayawhip'=>'FFEFD5',
        'peachpuff'=>'FFDAB9',
        'peru'=>'CD853F',
        'pink'=>'FFC0CB',
        'plum'=>'DDA0DD',
        'powderblue'=>'B0E0E6',
        'purple'=>'800080',
        'red'=>'FF0000',
        'rosybrown'=>'BC8F8F',
        'royalblue'=>'4169E1',
        'saddlebrown'=>'8B4513',
        'salmon'=>'FA8072',
        'sandybrown'=>'F4A460',
        'seagreen'=>'2E8B57',
        'seashell'=>'FFF5EE',
        'sienna'=>'A0522D',
        'silver'=>'C0C0C0',
        'skyblue'=>'87CEEB',
        'slateblue'=>'6A5ACD',
        'slategray'=>'708090',
        'slategrey'=>'708090',
        'snow'=>'FFFAFA',
        'springgreen'=>'00FF7F',
        'steelblue'=>'4682B4',
        'tan'=>'D2B48C',
        'teal'=>'008080',
        'thistle'=>'D8BFD8',
        'tomato'=>'FF6347',
        'turquoise'=>'40E0D0',
        'violet'=>'EE82EE',
        'wheat'=>'F5DEB3',
        'white'=>'FFFFFF',
        'whitesmoke'=>'F5F5F5',
        'yellow'=>'FFFF00',
        'yellowgreen'=>'9ACD32');

    $color_name = strtolower($color_name);
    if (isset($colors[$color_name]))
    {
        return ('#' . $colors[$color_name]);
    }
    else
    {
        return ($color_name);
    }
}
```

#### Get that function and don't do if already RGB:

```
$content__background_color = '#0000FF';
        if(strpos($content__background_color, 'rgb') !== false){
            $rgbarr = explode(",",$content__background_color,3);
            $colorname = sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x", $rgbarr[0], $rgbarr[1], $rgbarr[2]);
        } else {
            $colorname = self::color_name_to_hex($content__background_color);
        }
```

#### Convert to RGBA:

```
list($r, $g, $b) = array_map(function($c){return hexdec(str_pad($c, 2, $c));}, str_split(ltrim($colorname, '#'), strlen($colorname > 4 ? 2 : 1)));
        $send_to_less_example[ 'content-opacity-level' ] = "rgba($r, $g, $b, " . '75' / 100.00 . ')';
    return $send_to_less_example;
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is fine, you just have a wrong closing parenthesis at `strlen($colorname > 4 ? 2 : 1)` it should be `strlen($colorname) > 4 ? 2 : 1` so change it to be like this and you'll have it working:

```php
list($r, $g, $b) = array_map(
    function($c) {
        return hexdec(str_pad($c, 2, $c));
    },
    str_split(ltrim($colorname, '#'), strlen($colorname) > 4 ? 2 : 1)
);
```

You can see it working at [sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/675e788d717c2290e1ac92f2d3c19ffe775c92de).

Comment: Thank you! I will try that, if it works, I will accept your answer!

Comment: Thank you, It works! I can't believe I made that mistake!

Comment: @AlphaandOmega it can happen to all of us. Pay attention how I place such a nested array map call in my answer's code; I write it so I can see more clearly what it does, so when I will try to debug this, my eye will most likely catch that miss-closed parenthesis.  Try to avoid long one-line and nested code, it will help you so much on debuging.